# Replace a pipe on OSX terminal with Perl

Tags: perl, terminal

I would like to mass replace a pipe with an encoding (%7C) in multiple html files that are on a folder on my desktop. I have tried the following commands without any success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/sample_dir
perl -pi -e 's!Abel|Source!Abel%7CSource!g;' *.html
perl -pi -e 'sAbel|\/Source!Abel%7CSource!g;' *.html
perl -pi -e 'sAbel|\Source!Abel%7CSource!g;' *.html
```

Answer (score 3):

The pipe character is a special symbol in regular expressions (it means "or"), so it needs to be escaped with `\`.

```
perl -pi -e 's!Abel\|Source!Abel%7CSource!g' *.html
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this command does not work, both for html files in the desktop folder and some in subfolders.

Comment: I have a folder on my desktop called sample_dir. Inside this folder, I have html files and subfolders also containing html files. I have used cd /Users/me/Desktop/sample_dir with the terminal and then paste @davecross answer, but none of the files (html inside the folder and subfolders) were changed.

Comment: Please run `ls -lR ~/Desktop/sample_dir | pbcopy` and then click `edit` under your question and paste the listing from your Clipboard - select the listing and format as code by clicking `{}` in the Formatting menu.

Comment: @laurent: The test I just ran worked fine. It doesn't deal with sub-directories (because that's not what you originally asked for) but it successfully changed the files in my current directory. Are you sure that it's actually a pipe symbol in your files?